# Extending android picker

Tags: android

I am new to Android and need help with the NumberPicker widget. Android Number picker widget by default view shows 3 items i.e. current -1 , current, current + 1. (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)

I want to show for example 5 items

```
                          Sunday
                          Monday
                          **Tuesday**
                          Wednesday
                          Thursday
```

So far I am using a number picker and setting the value using setDisplayValues() method. I want to have the same animation as the NumberPicker provides, thats the reason I did not go for having 5 textViews and up and down button approach.

```
  NumberPicker picker = (NumberPicker)rootView.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
       picker.setMinValue(0);
       picker.setMaxValue(6);
       picker.setDisplayedValues( new String[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" } );
```

How can I achive this.